# How to create data struct that can update (delete/create/update) item in O(1) and to be thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, struct

I have some client application that get every 3 seconds a communication data that contain 1000 items. Each item contain 3 fields:

1. id (long)
2. Command (create/update/delete)
3. data (in case of update/create it will contain information about the item)

I don't know what data struct I need to choose to hold all those item. 
I don't want to hold simple hash Table because it can be very big because the id of the item can be large number at some point of the application running.

I must have the ability to find any item (by looking the id) quickly ... ( o(1) )

And there is a possibility that in some point of the application run => the communication that feen the items is coming from more than one costumers => that mean that I must keep the my data struct to be thread safe.

Comment: Check out Java's `ConcurrentHashMap`. Or put a lock on a normal hash map.

Comment: How about creating buckets of hash tables? In this case you can monitor each bucket with a mutex, such that when a thread works only one bucket is blocked rather then the whole data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are other considerations you should take into account:

- Does it need to be persistent if your application crashes?
- Is there a chance that it gets so big that it won't fit in memory?
- Is it possible that you might need to search through that data?

If you answered no to all, then use `ConcurrentHashMap<Long, YourDataObject>`. If you answered yes to any, then I'd strongly advise that you use some sort of database. Either a conventional DBMS like MySQL, or something like ElasticSearch to act as your data structure.

Comment: but without database ... in this teoretic issue i need persistent (lets say on disk when the application is down (only then) )and its possible to have big memory and also i must have ability to search .. but i need to keep all in the memory not on DB ( can't do io )

Comment: Then use ConcurrentHashMap. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html